# AS3: Need to removeChild before addChild?

Tags: actionscript-3, displaylist

I notice that you don't have to `removeChild` a `DisplayObject` from it's parent before `addChild`ing it to another container. If you just `addChild` it to the second container, it will automatically be removed from its current parent first. Is there any point to doing `removeChild` first if you're just going to `addChild` it someplace else right after?

Comment: Well, I suppose it would make the code more readable and your intentions more clear to other people, don't you think? Other than that, I don't see any downsides if the usecase is adding the displayobject to something else immediately (as opposed to removing it and adding it elsewhere at some further point in time).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, there is no point in doing `removeChild()` first. [The documentation](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/DisplayObjectContainer.html#addChild()) clearly describes this behavior:

> If you add a child object that already has a different display object container as a parent, the object is removed from the child list of the other display object container.

Adding a redundant call to `removeChild()` only bloats the code.